# Anti-aliasing in Carto markers makes them look "fuzzy"

Tags: qgis, cartography

Can you sharpen up the points in a Carto map so they have a less "fuzzy" aesthetic?

Here's what I've tried so far, and what I've learned:

- First of all, I *think* this issue is about anti-aliasing. I see CartoCSS options to change this for polygons and lines, but not markers
- I've tried adding a border or halo. But they are also fuzzy.
- I've tried setting other "blending" types. But I believe these refer to "the composite operation that defines how the symbolizer behaves relative to layers atop or below it." So not relevant here.
- I've tried to set the CSS marker-file to other marker types, but those are all fuzzy as well

Questions:

1. Does the fuzziness have to do with how the marker renders (anti-aliasing)? Is this just a Carto default?
2. Is there a CSS marker property that can change this? I went through all marker properties in the Carto docs and I'm not seeing anything.

(And, no, the fuzziness is not a function of me taking a screenshot. This is exactly what it looks like right in the Carto map.)

[image]

Comment: Your map looks pretty nice to me ... aren't u a bit picky ? or can u enlarge it ?
_could tell what's the name of the font u used for the labeling ?_

Comment: @snaileater Ha! This is actually a request from someone I'm doing work for. But thank you!

Comment: Did u try to add an underlying marker (white for example) or an "halo" (layer rendering/draw effects) in order to better discriminate your points ? but i fear an "halo" will remain too fuzzy for you ...

Comment: @snaileater I did try a halo, but you're right, same problem... And I think adding a whole second set of markers would just be too much and likely pose the same issue

Comment: Sorry to ask but ... what is the name of `the font` you used on this carto ? thanks !

Comment: @snaileater shoot, I'm not sure. It's just the "positron" basemap.